# Is there any downside to change the vCenter Server Appliance root pw via bash?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

VMware describes the process to change the vCenter Server Appliance root password [here](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vcsa.doc/GUID-48BAF973-4FD3-4FF3-B1B6-5F7286C9B59A.html).

It is a rather clumsy procedure involving the virtual console, which prevents me from using copy/paste from my password vault. I have to type in the password manually, which makes me want to use a simple, typable password.

Alternatively, I could log in via ssh, start a shell, and just use the good old `passwd` 
command to change the password on the command line. This way I could just copy/paste the password from my password vault.

Is there any downside to the latter approach? Why doesn't VMware describe it as an alternative?

Comment: If in a crash incident, do you expect your copy/paste to work? please use a password typable on a normal keyboard :)

Answer (score 0):

The root user is only meant for disaster recovery and updating purposes in vCenter, it's not to be used for managing vCenter (that's what the built in administrator account in the vsphere.local domain is for). As such, the only time you'll need the root password is if the vcenter doesn't function (for example the network is down) or you're updating it. In the first case being able to change it though SSH would be kinda pointless, and due to it's nature most people reset the password when they need it as it's used so rarely.

There's also a security aspect around it, that's why the only "official" way to change the password is through the console. SSH should also be normally disabled on a vCenter appliance.

As to your question if it can be changed through SSH I can not say, but I'm quite sure it's not supported.